# MuPDF error when changing device orientation

Tags: android, android-orientation, mupdf, android-pdf-api

I use MuPDF library to view PDF on android application , it's ok when viewing the pdf on portrait pode , but once change the orientation to landscape the app crash.

```
                    --------- beginning of crash
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.288 24024-24225/com.niveales.wind A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 24225 (AsyncTask #4)
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.314 24024-24035/com.niveales.wind I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2151(88KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(140KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 56MB/56MB, paused 1.192ms total 175.641ms
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.415 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.1.1/NYC/4316688:user/release-keys'
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: pid: 24024, tid: 24225, name: AsyncTask #4  >>> com.niveales.wind <<<
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000001  ebx 8e012df8  ecx 8e78a000  edx 00000000
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     esi 8e83ec80  edi 8e77d694
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.416 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     eip 8cf12b2a  ebp acab5bc0  esp 8e77d4d0  flags 00210202
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.418 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.418 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00144b2a  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.419 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 001454ba  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so (pdf_process_contents+490)
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.420 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000e024d  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.420 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000e0545  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so (pdf_run_page_contents+261)
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.420 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00046d1d  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so (fz_run_page_contents+173)
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.420 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00038487  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so (Java_com_artifex_mupdfdemo_MuPDFCore_drawPage+2087)
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.420 24519-24519/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00db2013  /data/app/com.niveales.wind-1/oat/x86/base.odex (offset 0xc90000)
                2019-01-14 15:50:41.695 22480-24462/? E/PhenotypeFlagCommitter: Retrieving snapshot for com.google.android.gms.rcs failed
                java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Task
                at arde.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):29)
                at akat.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):2)
                at akat.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):19)
                at akat.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):26)
                at qdv.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):5)
                at qdv.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):1)
                at com.google.android.gms.common.config.PhenotypeUpdateOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):3)
                at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):2)
                at duh.run(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):12)
                at due.run(:com.google.android.gms@14799022@14.7.99 (040700-223214910):9)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Does anyone know what wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in activity tag in manifest 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: it's working on Android 7.1.1 , but not working on Android 8.0 even without changing the scrren orientation. any idea ?